# two js files getting conflicted one is yadcf and other one is for buttons in data table plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, yadcf

I am new to data table plugin and jquery. I have added many js and css files to 
 my html page for data table plugin features,but when I added **yadcf 0.8.2** js 
file for enabling mulitple search bars at header,but this feature hide
buttons that leads to invisible of buttons.Is it regarding to css position or js 
file confliction. Please help me.I have added two images of previous html page
and page after adding **yadcf** js file.
  [**link for yadcf 0.9.1**](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/blob/master/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js)

[image for after loading **yadcf** file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GIXz.jpg)

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/dataTables.jqueryui.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.0/css/select.jqueryui.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.2/css/fixedHeader.dataTables.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/colreorder/1.3.2/css/colReorder.dataTables.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.2.2/css/fixedColumns.dataTables.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/rowreorder/1.1.2/css/rowReorder.dataTables.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ColumnFilterWidgets.css">


     <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/dataTables.jqueryui.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.0/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.0/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.2/js/dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/colreorder/1.3.2/js/dataTables.colReorder.min.js"></script>
                  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.2.2/js/dataTables.fixedColumns.min.js"></script>
              <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/rowreorder/1.1.2/js/dataTables.rowReorder.min.js"></script>

      <script src="ColumnFilterWidgets.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
                      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
                      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/js/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.18/build/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.18/build/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.5.0/jszip.min.js"></script>
<style>

.dt-buttons{
float:right;
 margin-left:125px;
 margin-bottom:7px;
 }


.dataTables_wrapper{
margin-top:10px;
}

</style>
</head>
    <body>
<p> User Setting</br><input id="chk" type="checkbox" name="your-group"/>Enable/Disable Fixed Header!</p>

<table id="example" class="display cell-border" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>No</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>No</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2012/03/29</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>2008/11/28</td>
                <td>$162,700</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>6</td>
                <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2012/12/02</td>
                <td>$372,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>7</td>
                <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2012/08/06</td>
                <td>$137,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>8</td>
                <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>55</td>
                <td>2010/10/14</td>
                <td>$327,900</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>9</td>
                <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>39</td>
                <td>2009/09/15</td>
                <td>$205,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>Sonya Frost</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>2008/12/13</td>
                <td>$103,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>11</td>
                <td>Jena Gaines</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2008/12/19</td>
                <td>$90,560</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>12</td>
                <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
                <td>Support Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2013/03/03</td>
                <td>$342,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>13</td>
                <td>Charde Marshall</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>36</td>
                <td>2008/10/16</td>
                <td>$470,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>14</td>
                <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
                <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>43</td>
                <td>2012/12/18</td>
                <td>$313,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>15</td>
                <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>19</td>
                <td>2010/03/17</td>
                <td>$385,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>16</td>
                <td>Michael Silva</td>
                <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2012/11/27</td>
                <td>$198,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>17</td>
                <td>Paul Byrd</td>
                <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>2010/06/09</td>
                <td>$725,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>18</td>
                <td>Gloria Little</td>
                <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2009/04/10</td>
                <td>$237,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>19</td>
                <td>Bradley Greer</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>41</td>
                <td>2012/10/13</td>
                <td>$132,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>20</td>
                <td>Dai Rios</td>
                <td>Personnel Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>35</td>
                <td>2012/09/26</td>
                <td>$217,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
                <td>Development Lead</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2011/09/03</td>
                <td>$345,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>Yuri Berry</td>
                <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>40</td>
                <td>2009/06/25</td>
                <td>$675,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>Caesar Vance</td>
                <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>2011/12/12</td>
                <td>$106,450</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>24</td>
                <td>Doris Wilder</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>Sidney</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>2010/09/20</td>
                <td>$85,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>25</td>
                <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
                <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2009/10/09</td>
                <td>$1,200,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>26</td>
                <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>42</td>
                <td>2010/12/22</td>
                <td>$92,575</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>27</td>
                <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>28</td>
                <td>2010/11/14</td>
                <td>$357,650</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>28</td>
                <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>28</td>
                <td>2011/06/07</td>
                <td>$206,850</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>29</td>
                <td>Fiona Green</td>
                <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>48</td>
                <td>2010/03/11</td>
                <td>$850,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>Shou Itou</td>
                <td>Regional Marketing</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>20</td>
                <td>2011/08/14</td>
                <td>$163,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>31</td>
                <td>Michelle House</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Sidney</td>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>2011/06/02</td>
                <td>$95,400</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>32</td>
                <td>Suki Burks</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>53</td>
                <td>2009/10/22</td>
                <td>$114,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
                <td>Technical Author</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>27</td>
                <td>2011/05/07</td>
                <td>$145,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>34</td>
                <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
                <td>Team Leader</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2008/10/26</td>
                <td>$235,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>35</td>
                <td>Martena Mccray</td>
                <td>Post-Sales support</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>46</td>
                <td>2011/03/09</td>
                <td>$324,050</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>36</td>
                <td>Unity Butler</td>
                <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2009/12/09</td>
                <td>$85,675</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>51</td>
                <td>2008/12/16</td>
                <td>$164,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>38</td>
                <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
                <td>Secretary</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>41</td>
                <td>2010/02/12</td>
                <td>$109,850</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>39</td>
                <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
                <td>Financial Controller</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>62</td>
                <td>2009/02/14</td>
                <td>$452,500</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var table= $('#example').DataTable( {


          "pagingType":"full_numbers",
          select: true,
          fixedHeader: {
                   header: true,
            },
          colReorder: true,
          fixedColumns:   {
                   leftColumns: 0
                            },
          rowReorder: true,
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
          lengthMenu:[
                     [10,25,50,-1],
                     ['10 rows', '25 rows', '50 rows', 'Show all']
                     ],

                  buttons: [
            {

                extend: 'print',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: ':visible',
                }
            },
              {
                            extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                            exportOptions: {
                                columns: ':visible',
                            }
            },
            {
                            extend: 'excelHtml5',
                            exportOptions: {
                                columns: ':visible'
                            }
            },
            'colvis','pageLength', 'copy', 'csv'
        ],
        columnDefs: [ {
            targets: -1,
            visible: false

        } ],

              scrollY:        true,
              deferRender:    true,
              scroller:       true,

              scrollCollapse: true,
              "sDom": 'W<"clear">lfrtip'

       } );

    $('#chk').on( 'click', function () {
            if($('#chk').prop('checked')){
                table.fixedHeader.enable();
                alert('Enabled Fixed Header');
            }
            else if(!$('#chk').prop('checked')){
                table.fixedHeader.disable();
                alert('Disabled Fixed Header');
            }
    });
    });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Hi, in the code you shared us there isn't a link to the yadcfjs file. Could you add it and refresh your post?

Comment: Its working fine.Actually I had defined two dom parameters.i.e sDom parameter,that's why it was getting conflicted.